# DataPower XA35 - processing rule - Route Action

Tags: ibm-datapower

Our processing rule includes two Tranform actions, and a Validate, and Results actions. We want to add another action between the two transform actions to do the following:

The new action will use an XSLT to evaluate an expression. If there is a match, skip the rest of the processing rule actions to go to the last Results actions. Otherwise, continue processing the rest of the actions provided by the processing rule.

What type of action do I need to use to provide this solution, perhaps "Route Action"? If yes, what would the syntax be in the xslt file to call the last Results action?

Please provide any advise.

Thank You - Eneo.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest firmware, there is a "Conditional" Action, using which you can skip actions.